# How to overlay a heat map onto spatial map in R?

Tags: r, heatmap

I am looking for help in creating a heat map of sorts that can overlay a spatial map. I have multiple data points, such as temperature, along coordinates in a river and would like to be able to visualize the change in temperature along the river (for example: higher temperature would be shown as red and lower temperature blue). Is this possible? I've gone through the different heat map questions and can't seem to piece it together.

This code gives the closest representation I think, but I don't know how to adapt it to what I need:

```
sample <- data.frame(Longitude=c(-1+rnorm(50,0,.5),-2+rnorm(50,0,0.5),-4.5+rnorm(50,0,.5)),
                     Latitude =c(52+rnorm(50,0,.5),54+rnorm(50,0,0.5),56+rnorm(50,0,.5)))
CanMap  <- readOGR(dsn="gadm-CAN-shapefile",layer="gadm36_CAN_2")
map.df <- fortify(CanMap)

ggplot(sample, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)) + 
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha=0.5, geom="polygon")+
  geom_point(colour="red")+
  geom_path(data=map.df,aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group), colour="grey50")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(7,"Spectral")))+
  xlim(-10,+2.5) +
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: I think you're looking to create a chloropleth map?

Comment: The problem is I don't have predefined areas, such as county or province lines. Would it still be a chloropleth map?

Comment: You could create a SHP file out of it or you could just plot as scatter plot on top of the map. Do you have a framework you're using for mapping? Leaflet is usually my recommendation. https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html